# text in boxes not changing with DOM code

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

i am trying to have the boxes marked "time of call" and "date" to contain the current time and date while the checkbox "now" is checked. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Is onClick being called?

my code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ben7005/nWEm8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was that i was using a variable called ampm when ampm was a function.